# How to check safety of car rental offer in Spain?

Tags: car-rentals, scams

I did a Barcelona car rental search on Kayak while on WiFi in Lisbon airport.  Kayak passed me off to "Holiday Rentals" which says "OK rent a car" with thousands of positive reviews will charge US$7.42 TOTAL for seven days and include CDW.  If it were only the unbelievably low price, I'd suspect a trap.  Yet all other signs seem legit.  I wonder whether on turn in, they'll say something like "that dent wasn't there before and the repair will be a thousand bucks more than your CDW limit."  OR, since they have a shuttle pickup at the airport, could it be a trick to get someone to a remote place for a shake-down?

Comment: `a shuttle pickup at the airport, could it be a trick to get someone to a remote place for a shake-down?` That is way too paranoid. Someone operating this way would be caught very fast (security cameras at the airport capturing the shuttle licence plate, the driver, etc.) and it is a setup too expensive and complicated (shuttle, web page, etc.) for just mugging the random tourist (once an issue of this kind was detected it would be trivial for the police to check shuttles). Oh, and there is a big rental company with that name (I considered it as an option for buying an used car).

Comment: Well, I am half-convinced.  But I think I'll go to their office in person rather than book online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Youre missing some conditions on the rental.

After a search through kayak, i've seen some offers as low as 9€, and **these are the conditions of those given directly by kayak** (7 days, 29€ total the lowest):

**Pay online and get a 75% off** ( weird offer, but acceptable and legit-esque ).

**Total does not include fuel charges**, car deposit must be returned full.

**KM policy :** 0.157 EUR  per KM, with a maxium total of 1600km.

**Rental Insurance :** you need to have 1110.0€ on your account, that will be locked to ensure the car's not damaged or stolen, and that will be unlocked and returned on car return.

**<25 drivers:** drivers between ages 21 and 25 will be charged 5€ daily up to a maximum of 60€.

**Additional drivers:** any additional driver will cost 5€ daily.

So the real cost will go at around 60-70€ or more given that you'll have to replenish the diposit + 7 days of kilometers.

Comment: Hmmm, they clearly said it was the total.  And they wanted all the credit card info before giving any other total.  I think I'll hold off till I am in an actual office.

Comment: it can be the "Reserve total", not the whole total. They don't know how many KM you're gonna drive until you've driven them.

Comment: If it scares you, you could always pick one that has a fully free cancelation fee. That's what i do with hotels too.

Comment: In the end, I decided to go with the known, Enterprise, partly because it was right in the train station.  But they had no cars, so I went to the only other place visible, and they had none.

Comment: @WGroleau none had any cars? that's really strange. did you try with Hertz? they always have cars unless it's a special holiday, which was not.

Comment: Only those two that were at the train station.  No point in renting a car if I have to take a bus to get to their office.  Might as well take the bus to a hotel in the center of the city.  From there, I can bus or walk to anything.

Comment: What train station did you stop by? i'm sorry you couldn't fine one.

Comment: Lisbon Oriente hasta Burgos Rosa de Lima.  Hay otro?

Comment: No, there aren't more near the train station, sadly. there are a lot of them ( good ones like Hertz, Europcar) near the city centre if you need a rented car to visit countrisyde places buses don't go.

Comment: I meant another train station (you asked which one).  Unless I am in a hurry, I get places on foot or bicycle.